# New and trying to get python set up with Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext

I've been trying for the past few hours now to get sublime text to work with python but it just keeps giving me the same message.

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

I have Python 3.10.4 installed I've tried to uninstall and reinstall a few times but I still get the same massage.
same with sublime text.

Thanks

Comment: If all else fail, please give PyCharm a try. I am using it for most of my Python projects now and JetBrain did a really great job!

Comment: maybe you have to change settings and use `/full/path/to/your/python` - or you have to add folder with Python to environment variable `PATH`. And reinstalling may not help.